# PERN project modifying all entries in database instead of the one specified

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, postgresql, express

I've been working on library application in my free time and I have run into a problem I cannot figure out.  I am trying to update information for a specific book, however, every time I update the book, it is applied to all of the entries in the database instead of the one intended, obviously this is problem.  I have tried everything I can think to make the program apply the changes to only the item in question.  It is a PERN Stack application.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Express side (the library_id is generated automatically in PostgreSQL

```
//update book

app.put("/update/:library_id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { title } = req.body;
    const { author } = req.body;
    const { genre } = req.body;
    const { published } = req.body;
    const { description } = req.body;
    const updateBook = await pool.query(
      "UPDATE library SET title = $1, author = $2, genre = $3, published = $4, description = $5 WHERE library_id = library_id",
      [title, author, genre, published, description]
    );

    res.json("book was updated");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

React.js side

```
function EditBook({ book }) {
  console.log(book);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(book.title);
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState(book.author);
  const [genre, setGenre] = useState(book.genre);
  const [published, setPublished] = useState(book.published);
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(book.description);

  //update method
  const updateBook = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const body = { title, author, genre, published, description };
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:5000/update/${book.library_id}`,
        {
          method: "PUT",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify(body),
        }
      );

      window.location = "/";
      console.log(response);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `library_id`? To me it would signify an entire library. My guess is you are looking for something more like `book_id`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, library_id is what PostgreSQL assigns each item made in the database.  Here is the table from PostgreSQL. ```pernlibrary=# SELECT * FROM library;
 library_id | title | author | genre | published | description 
------------+-------+--------+-------+-----------+-------------
        123 | Test  | Test   | Test  |      1234 | Test

Comment: Then that case the `WHERE library_id = library_id` is an issue as you are telling the database to `UPDATE` all rows having a `library_id`. If you want to specify a single item/book then you will need to provide a unique value for `library_id` like `WHERE library_id = 123`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, thank you!  I just tried it, I made library_id = 136 (a specific item in the database), however, the problem persisted, all items still changed over to the new data.

Comment: Well does not make sense. The only thing I can think of is to check the Postgres log and see what is actually hitting the server.  You would need `log_statement='mod'`, at the least,  in postgresql.conf.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, Oh, I don't even have a postgresql.conf file.

Comment: If there is a Postgres instance there is a postgresql.conf file. Where is the Postgres instance you are querying?